# How to properly index list items to return rows, not columns, inside a for loop

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I'm trying to write a for loop within another for loop. The first loop grabs the ith vcov matrix from a list of variously sized matrices (vcmats below) and grabs a frame of 24 predictor models of appropriate dimension to multiply with the current vcov matrix from a list of frames (jacobians below) for the different models. The second loop should pull the jth record (row) from the selected predictor frame, correctly format it, then run the calculation with the vcov matrix and output an indicator variable and calculated result needed for post processing to the holding table (holdtab).

When I run the code below I get the following error: Error in jjacob[, 1:4] : incorrect number of dimensions because R is returning the column of 1s (i.e. the intercept column of jacobs), not the complete first record (i.e. jjacob = jacobs[1,]). I've substantially simplified the example but left enough complexity to demonstrate the problem. I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

```
vcmats <- list(structure(c(0.67553, -0.1932, -0.00878, -0.00295, -0.00262, 
-0.00637, -0.1932, 0.19988, 0.00331, -0.00159, 0.00149, 2e-05, 
-0.00878, 0.00331, 0.00047, -6e-05, 3e-05, 3e-05, -0.00295, -0.00159, 
-6e-05, 0.00013, -2e-05, 6e-05, -0.00262, 0.00149, 3e-05, -2e-05, 
2e-05, 0, -0.00637, 2e-05, 3e-05, 6e-05, 0, 0.00026), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L)), structure(c(0.38399, -0.03572, -0.00543, -0.00453, -0.00634, 
-0.03572, 0.10912, 0.00118, -0.00044, 0.00016, -0.00543, 0.00118, 
0.00042, -3e-05, 4e-05, -0.00453, -0.00044, -3e-05, 0.00011, 
5e-05, -0.00634, 0.00016, 4e-05, 5e-05, 0.00025), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L)))

jacobians <- list(structure(list(intcpt = c(1, 1, 1, 1), species = c(1, 1, 
0, 0), nage = c(6, 6, 6, 6), T = c(12, 50, 12, 50), hgt = c(90, 
90, 90, 90), moon = c(7, 7, 7, 7), hXm = c(0, 0, 0, 0), covr = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), het = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("intcpt", "species", 
"nage", "T", "hgt", "moon", "hXm", "covr", "het"), row.names = c("1", 
"1.4", "1.12", "1.16"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    intcpt = c(1, 1, 1, 1), species = c(1, 1, 0, 0), nage = c(6, 
    6, 6, 6), T = c(12, 50, 12, 50), hgt = c(0, 0, 0, 0), moon = c(7, 
    7, 7, 7), hXm = c(0, 0, 0, 0), covr = c(0, 0, 0, 0), het = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("intcpt", "species", "nage", "T", "hgt", 
"moon", "hXm", "covr", "het"), row.names = c("2", "2.4", "2.12", 
"2.16"), class = "data.frame"))

holdtab <- structure(list(model = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), .Label = c("M.1.BaseCov", "M.2.Height", "M.5.Height.X.LastNewMoon", 
"M.6.Height.plus.LastNew", "M.7.LastNewMoon", "M.G.Global"), class = "factor"), 
    aicc = c(341.317, 341.317, 341.317, 341.317, 342.1412, 342.1412, 
    342.1412, 342.1412), species = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), condVar = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("model", 
"aicc", "species", "condVar"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), class = "data.frame")

jloop <- 1
for (imat in vcmats) {                      # Call the outside loop of vcov matrices
    jacobs = jacobians[[jloop]]             # Set tempvar jacobs as the jth member of the jacobians frame (n/24)
    for (jjacob in jacobs) {                # Call inside loop of lines in jacob (each individual set of predictor levels)
                                        # I need to reduce the vector length to match my vcov matrix so
    pt1 = jjacob[,1:4]                      # Separate Core columns from variable columns (because I don't want to drop species when ==0)
    pt2 = jjacob[,5:9]                      # Pull out variable columns for next step
    pt2 = pt2[,!apply(pt2 == 0, 2, all)]    # Drop any variable columns that ==0
    jjacob = cbind(pt1, pt2)                    # Reconstruct the record now of correct dimensions for the relevant vcov matrix
    jjacob = as.matrix(jjacob)              # Explicitly convert jjmod - I was having trouble with this previously
    tj = (t(jjacob))                            # Transpose the vector
    condvar = jjacob %*% imat %*% tj            # run the calculation
    condVarTab[record,3] = jjacob[2]            # Write species 0 or 1 to the output table
    condVarTab[record,4] = condvar          # Write the conditional variance to the table
    record = record+1                       # Iterate the record number for the next output run
        }
    jloop = jloop+1                         # Once all 24 models in a frame are calculated iterate to the next frame of models which will be associated with a new vcv matrix
    }
```

Comment: Your second `for` call should read: `for (j in nrow(jacobs))`. Modify `pt1 = jjacob[,1:4]; pt2 = jjacob[,5:9]` to `pt1 = jacobs[j,1:4]; pt2 = jacobs[j,5:9]`. Loop over the row of the data frame, since you already pull it from the list with the `jacobs = jacobians[[jloop]]`. Not sure what "condVarTab" and "record" are doing. Not define in your loop or elsewhere.

Comment: Right now, "jjacobs" is a counter, not a data frame, and the sequence that R is taking is the first column of "jacobs". So "jjacobs" is just a vector of 1s.

Comment: @paqmo Thanks for the tips. The loop now appears to be running, but the output is wrong. "condVarTab" should have been "holdtab", the table for holding output, and 'record' is just a counter moving through each holdtab record. When I run the corrected code the output only receives two output values, the last calculation for the first loop, and the last for the second loop. It is not adding the first three iterations to the holdtab table. I've tried several different approaches which work if I run through it line by line but not when the whole loop runs. Any thoughts on the cause or solution?

Comment: Got it! The second `for` call should read: `for(j in 1:nrow(jacobs))`, not just `for (j in nrow(jacobs))`. Thanks @paqmo for heading me down the right path.